# selenium-webdriver in nodejs sample not returning current title

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I was working through the selenium web-driver example and it didn't work.  Several months ago it worked just fine so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if the testing methods have changed.

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var By = webdriver.By;

test.describe('Google Search', function() {
    test.it('should work', function(done) {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
            withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
            build();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
            assert.equal("webdriver - Google Search", title);
            done();
        });

        driver.quit();
    });
});
```

The output is:

```
AssertionError: "webdriver - Google Search" == "Google"
Expected :"Google"
Actual   :"webdriver - Google Search"
```

This tells me that the page has not updated yet but I am not sure why.  The example appears here:  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Getting_Started

Selenium version from package.json: 2.39.0

## Update

I should have also stated that the test is being run through Mocha.  Is Mocha the culprit?  When I tried this last time it was using Jasmine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from [the example in the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Getting_Started), use `wait`:

```
driver.wait(function() {
 return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
   return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
 });
}, 1000);
```

Why do you need to use wait? Because the Google page works asynchronously. After you enter the keys, it may take a bit of time before the server sends a response and the page is updated.

You should also remove `done`. While in general you need it for asynchronous tests, it seems the sequencer that comes with this incarnation of Selenium's webdriver will block on `quit` until all actions are performed. This [example](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Writing_Tests) in the documentation does not use it.

Also, if you wonder why there is no assertion: you'll know your test has failed if you get a timeout exception when the timeout has expired.

Comment: I tried every variant in the examples including the pyramid of doom call back.  I think that there is a conflict between mocha+chai+webdriver. I am able to get the promise chain to work: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows

Comment: I was editing my answer while you were writing. At any rate, the code I show you in my answer works when I run it here.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I suspect that it is a configuration issue on my part and probably not easily duplicated.  I'll delete the question and plus up another answer of yours.  Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: Turned out you were absolutely correct.  The js side could really use a cookbook.  It took me 2 days that could have been summed up in a sentence.  `Driver.wait() will execute a function every x milliseconds until it returns true.`